# Where in query on Primary key vs where query on other inexed column performance

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have a table **saleItem**

```
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id            | char(16)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| expiry_date   | char(8)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| status        | varchar(10)  | NO   | MUL |         |       |
| last_update   | datetime     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| status_change | datetime     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Here **id** is the primary key. This table has millions of entries out of which **status** can five values. I would like to use update query on this table using **status**. When I use :

```
UPDATE saleItem SET status="aa" where status="bb";
```

I get the following exception, since this table is updated by other application as well:

> SQLException: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

Would using subquery like below would solve the problem:

```
selectedIds=SELECT id FROM saleItem WHERE status='bb'

UPDATE saleItem SET status="aa" where id in (selectedIds);
```

Will this query work?

What about the performance of this query?

Are there any better ways to handle this?

Create table query:

```
CREATE TABLE `saleItem` (
  `id` char(16) NOT NULL,
  `expiry_date` char(8) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `last_update` datetime NOT NULL,
  `status_change` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `expiry_date_idx` (`expiry_date`),
  KEY `status_idx` (`status`),
  KEY `last_update_idx` (`last_update`),
  KEY `status_change_idx` (`status_change`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: You should show us the query that is causing you problems. You should also show us the `explain` output for the query. And the indexes from the table.

Comment: Sure I will update the query

Comment: Let's call your transaction (attempt) T2. What is T1 doing? Innodb?

Comment: Generally speaking sub-query `UPDATE saleItem SET status="aa" where id in (SELECT id FROM saleItem WHERE status='bb')` would not solve "Lock wait timeout exceed".

I think the first step is to find which query has **LOCK** longer. Have you run `SHOW PROCESSLIST;` or `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` to check which one runs long?

Comment: @AsConfused: T2 is something like. UPDATE saleItem SET status="cc" where id="xyz". This id may or may not be in " SELECT id FROM saleItem WHERE status='bb' "

Comment: I would have thought you could test as quickly as ask

Comment: @Strawberry: Have to make changes on production server. And I cant test locally as I have resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have only 5 distinct values of `status`?  Make it an `ENUM`.  That will take 1 byte instead of the several you have now.  Smaller --> faster.

Only 5 values?  For some of the values, your `UPDATE` will do a table scan instead of using the index!  For this reason, it is generally a bad idea to index columns with low cardinality.

Here's another reason:  The `UPDATE` is changing `status`.  That implies (1) changing the data in the table, (2) removing an index entry containing the old value, and (3) inserting a new index entry with the new value.  That's 3 steps, not just 1!

How can the `UPDATE` be efficient without `INDEX(status)`?  Look at a different [chunking technique](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks) -- one that involves walking through the `PRIMARY KEY` efficiently.  (That blog refers to `DELETEs`, but the chunking applies to `UPDATEs`, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

No, using the subquery will not solve the problem, not directly, if it's attempting to update the same set of rows. I think the issue is that you are trying to update too many rows at the same time, and you're running into contention with locks (other sessions holding locks on rows.)

I'd try breaking that huge transaction up into smaller chunks, get a few thousand rows at a time. Something like this:

```
  UPDATE saleItem SET status='aa' where status='bb' LIMIT 4000;
```

And repeat that multiple times, until the number of rows updated is zero.

Is `status` a leading column in an index? It's not clear what indexes are available in the table. The output from `SHOW CREATE TABLE saleitem` would give us a better picture of what indexes exist.

If there's not a suitable index on `status`, then likely MySQL is going to start at the beginning of the table, and start looking at rows. It shouldn't take too long to find 4000 rows to update. The next time around, if it starts at the beginning of the table again, it will need to look at even more rows.

So, to do this  I definitely would want to get an index used. We might try something like

```
CREATE TABLE bb_id
( ai INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
, id CHAR(16) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);
INSERT INTO bb_id (id) SELECT id FROM saleitem WHERE status = 'bb';
```

Then I could use a join operation to update batches of rows.

```
UPDATE saleitem s
  JOIN bb_id b
    ON b.id = s.id
   SET s.status = 'aa' 
 WHERE s.status = 'bb'
   AND b.ai  > 0
   AND b.ai <= 4000
```

The next run,

```
   AND b.ai  > 4000
   AND b.ai <= 8000
```

etc.

That's no guarantee that you won't run into LOCK TIMEOUT issues, but the transactions you're running will be more reasonably sized. You might want to do more that 4000 rows at a pop, or maybe fewer. But this is the approach I would take.

Comment: As you mentioned, we had limited this to 500. But even with those change, I was getting lock timeout issues.

Comment: @user2627846: I'm wondering if *any* of 500 row batch succeeded, or even if a single row update succeeded. I suspect that some other database session may be holding locks on some (or all) of the rows that need to be updated for a really long time (an uncommitted transaction perhaps?).

Answer (score 0):

From the table structure you have provided, i would make a few points:

1. You are using a varchar(10) for your status, and this has no KEY/INDEX on it.
   This would result in a table scan happening at every interval to try and work out what records have got the status of "bb".
2. i would do this in a 2 part query honestly if you dont want to put the index on. The issues is that when you are updating the table, you are also changing your mix by updating the values in the same column, so the table scan is locking the update.

I would do the following SQL:

```
UPDATE saleItem 
SET status= "aa" 
WHERE id IN (SELECT 
             Id 
             FROM saleItem 
             WHERE status="bb");
```

The SQL Above would firstly go and grab all the ID's where the status is "bb" and then update them after it has recieved the full list.

Comment: If you don't have a new enough version of MySQL, the `IN ( SELECT ... )` construct will perform _terribly slowly_.